# ArcGIS Web adaptor for Portal login link fails

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-enterprise, arcgis-web-adaptor

I have ArcGIS Server installed on a server behind my company's firewall and a web adaptor pointing to it on a DMZ server. Both are working (I can see unsecured services while using the web adaptor URL), but the login link doesn't work when accessed from the web adaptor. Clicking the login link simply leads the user to a blank page. The login function works when accessed from arc server directly. How can I fix this?

Here's what I've discovered in my troubleshooting efforts so far:

-The expiration time in minutes for the token was set to -1. I updated it to 1440 and restarted the server. Didn't work. ( https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000013440 )

-Ports 80 and 443 are open on the DMZ server. Ports 80, 443, 6080, 6443, 7080, 7443, 7099, 7654 are open on the application server behind the firewall. They are not competing with other applications.

-IWA federation is enabled on the back end server.

Comment: is the DMZ a reverse proxy? > https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/deploy/linux/using-a-reverse-proxy-server-with-arcgis-server.htm

Comment: Yes, it is. The web adaptor is set up outside the firewall.

Comment: Any messages in the network/console tabs when you get the white screen?  To confirm, you have a portal + GIS Server federated back in the trusted zone, and the web adaptor is in the DMZ?  Can you take IWA out of the mix and rely on Portal Identity store for troubleshooting?